# How to dynamically change the API_BASE_URL from nswag generated typescript Angular client

Tags: angular, typescript, nswag

I would like to dynamically change the API_BASE_URL configured in my typescript client generated by NSWAG.
I would like to use the same client with one API_BASE_URL within an angular module and another API_BASE_URL within another Angular module.
Is this possible ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the providers Property in your Modules where you want to use the NSWAG Generated Clients?

Just an Example:

```
ModuleA
    providers: [
        {
            provide: API_BASE_URL, useValue: 'your-desired-value',
        },
        CustomerQueryClient, // Client from NSWAG Generated File
        CustomerCommandClient // Client from NSWAG Generated File
    ]

ModuleB
    providers: [
        {
            provide: API_BASE_URL, useValue: 'your-desired-value',
        },
        CustomerQueryClient, // Client from NSWAG Generated File
        CustomerCommandClient // Client from NSWAG Generated File
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I've tried to configure it in 2 different modules with 2 different values and the first one wich has instantiated my client has won.
What I can see in the generated client is that this API_BASE_URL is a constant ...

Comment: I've done this in 2 different modules:
 {
      provide: API_BASE_URL,
      useValue: 'http://test1.com',
    },

Comment: I've updated my Example.
Did you also provide, in each Module, your Clients, as shown above?

Comment: Yes for each module with different values with "useValue" and not "value"

Comment: It is absolutely necessary to add the clients to the provider list so that they are re-instantiated for each module.

Comment: That's perfect ! Thank you